# Develop a HTTP Monitor in C#

Tags: c#, .net, http

I'd like to develop an application to monitor HTTP traffic to/from my PC. (what websites are being visited by the PC user).

The problem is, that I couldn't get any articles how to start developing application like that.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**[WinPcap](http://www.winpcap.org/): The Windows Packet Capture Library**

Its very powerfull [**WireShark**](http://www.wireshark.org/) uses it.

There is C# port of this library available called **[SharpPCap](http://www.tamirgal.com/blog/page/SharpPcap.aspx)**.

[**SharpPcap - A Packet Capture Framework for .NET**](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/sharppcap.aspx) - Code Project

Answer (score 4):

There's a .Net app called Fiddler which has this functionality; for use in your app, there's the [FiddlerCore](http://fiddler.wikidot.com/fiddlercore) component

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the free [Pcap.Net](http://pcapdotnet.codeplex.com) project.

It is a wrapper for WinPcap that includes a packet interpretation framework, which should make monitoring HTTP traffic pretty easy.